# React acting very strangely: sets variable and after that the varible falls back to initial value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
export default function SpecificPostCommentsExtended({ article }) {
  const [prev, setPrev] = useState("");
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);
  function changePrevState(_id) {
    setPrev(_id);
    console.log(_id, "-is id");
    console.log(prev, "- prev");
  }
  const ifNoCom = async () => {
    setLoaded(true);
    setTimeout(function () {
      document
        .querySelector("#confirm")
        .addEventListener("click", async () => {
          const data = await axios({
            url: vars.BACKENDURL + "/comment",
            withCredentials: true,
            method: "POST",
            data: {
              article: article,
              comment: {
                content: document.querySelector("#commentcontent").value,
                prevId: prev === "" ? null : prev,
              },
            },
          });
          setLoaded(true);
        });
    }, 30);
    return;
  };
  const ifCom = async () => {
    let i = 0;
    await article.commentsArr.forEach(async (c) => {
      const { data } = await axios({
        url: vars.BACKENDURL + "/getcomment",
        withCredentials: true,
        method: "POST",
        data: { comment: { _id: c } },
      });
      if (!comments.includes({ ...data })) {
        setComments((current) => [...current, { ...data }]);
      }
      i++;
      if (i === article.commentsArr.length - 1) {
        setLoaded(true);
        document
          .querySelector("#confirm")
          .addEventListener("click", async () => {
            console.log("It's prev - ", prev, "!lalalal");
            const data = await axios({
              url: vars.BACKENDURL + "/comment",
              withCredentials: true,
              method: "POST",
              data: {
                article: article,
                comment: {
                  content: document.querySelector("#commentcontent").value,
                  prevId: prev === "" ? null : prev,
                },
              },
            });
          });
      }
    });
  };
  const getComments = async () => {
    setComments([]);
    setLoaded(false);
    if (article.commentsArr.length === 0) {
      ifNoCom();
    } else {
      ifCom();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getComments();
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <Header>
        <HeaderImg src="../../assets/headerpic.png" />
        <Navbar>
          <span>mypage</span>| <span>log out</span>
        </Navbar>
      </Header>
      <Content>
        <SideBar />
        <RightFrame>
          {loaded === false ? (
            <CircularProgress />
          ) : (
            <>
              <UpperBlock>
                <Title>
                  {article.group.toLowerCase()}
                  <Subtitle>
                    <span>previous</span>
                    <span>next</span>
                    <span>list</span>
                  </Subtitle>
                </Title>

                <PostContainer>
                  <PostDecription>
                    <div className="left">
                      <h2>{article.title}</h2>
                      <span>{article.writer}</span>
                      <span>{article.date}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="right">
                      <span
                        onClick={async () => {
                          window.location = `/${article._id}/edit`;
                        }}
                      >
                        edit
                      </span>
                      <span>|</span>
                      <span
                        onClick={async () => {
                          if (
                            !window.confirm(
                              "Are you sure you want to delete this post?",
                            )
                          ) {
                            return;
                          }
                          const { data } = await axios({
                            url: vars.BACKENDURL + `/deletepost`,
                            withCredentials: true,
                            method: "DELETE",
                            data: {
                              post: {
                                id: article._id,
                              },
                            },
                          });
                          alert(data);
                        }}
                      >
                        delete
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </PostDecription>
                  <PostContents>
                    <h3>Contents</h3>
                    <p>{article.content}</p>
                  </PostContents>
                </PostContainer>
              </UpperBlock>
              <LowerBlock>
                <ReportBtns>
                  <ReportBtnMock>inappropriate language</ReportBtnMock>
                  <ReportBtnMock>misinformation</ReportBtnMock>
                </ReportBtns>
                <LowerRightFrame>
                  <div>
                    <span
                      onClick={() => {
                        window.location = "/specificpost/" + article._id;
                      }}
                    >
                      <img src="../../assets/comments.png" /> Comments{" "}
                      {article.comments}
                    </span>

                    <span
                      onClick={async () => {
                        const { data } = await axios({
                          url: vars.BACKENDURL + "/like",
                          method: "POST",
                          withCredentials: true,
                          data: {
                            post: article,
                          },
                        });
                        alert(data);
                      }}
                    >
                      <img src="../../assets/likes.png" /> Likes{" "}
                      {article.likes}
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <span>Like</span>
                    <span>|</span>
                    <span>Report</span>
                  </div>
                </LowerRightFrame>
                <CommentsBlock>
                  {comments.map((c, i) => {
                    console.log("C comment id", c.comment._id);
                    const _id = c.comment._id;
                    return (
                      <>
                        <Comment key={i}>
                          <Nickname>{c.comment.author}</Nickname>
                          <Contents>{c.comment.content}</Contents>
                          <LowerCommentContainer>
                            <span>{c.comment.date}</span>
                            <span
                              onClick={(e) => {
                                changePrevState(_id);
                              }}
                            >
                              reply
                            </span>
                          </LowerCommentContainer>
                        </Comment>
                        {c.subcomments.map((sc, j) => {
                          return (
                            <SubComment key={j}>
                              <Nickname>{sc.author}</Nickname>
                              <Contents>
                                @{sc.author}, <br /> {sc.content}
                              </Contents>
                              <LowerCommentContainer>
                                <span>{sc.date}</span>
                              </LowerCommentContainer>
                            </SubComment>
                          );
                        })}
                      </>
                    );
                  })}
                  <ContentsInput id="commentcontent" />
                  <Confirm id="confirm">Post</Confirm>
                </CommentsBlock>
              </LowerBlock>
            </>
          )}
        </RightFrame>
      </Content>
    </>
  );
}
```

Onclick Event's attached to span with label "reply" console logs tell me

```
60c6f3a623961520f85c23f7 -is id
60c6f3a623961520f85c23f7 - prev
```

Yet the useEffect's responsible for sending data to Db console logs tell me:

```
It's prev -   !lalalal
```

So it appears that the prev first gets set and then falls back to initial "" empty string value.
Can you please help me make out how to set the value to that useState hook, what am I doing wrong? Maybe useState variable is overwritten somewhere else and I juts don't know about it? I feel like I'm missing a minor but important!

Comment: This is explained in the React Hooks FAQ. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function

Comment: You should not... no, you _must not_ use `document.querySelector()` with React.

Comment: There's also really no reason why `ifCom` and `ifNoCom` would be separate functions. If there are no comments to load, they behave the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an empty array as the second param, your `useEffect` runs once and once only at the very beginning of the component's lifecycle. At the time of running, the state value is always the initial value `""`. As a result, the value of `prev` inside the click handler is always `""` since that's essentially a snapshot of the state at the time when `useEffect` runs.

Instead of `document.querySelector("#confirm").addEventListener`, add the `onClick` handler on `Confirm` directly and access `prev` inside. This allows you to get the latest of `prev` value at the time of clicking.

```
  <Confirm id="confirm" onClick={() => console.log('prev value', prev}}>Post</Confirm>
```

Ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function

Comment: Or you can use an `useLatest` hook to "unbox" the state value in the callback, as per https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function

Comment: @AKX Nice! Added the ref to my post. You should write up the `useLatest` solution as a separate answer :P